# Working Bootstrap/Chart.JS/JavaScript - make size of graphs proportionate to screen

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, chart.js

I'm trying to learn to work with Bootstrap, Chart.JS, and JavaScript in general.  I've been able to work off a template, however every graph on my .html file is huge.  I'd like everything to fit in proportion to my screen.  In other words, I want all of my graphs to appear without having to scroll down a bunch.  How would I go about doing that? What specific place I would need to enter height: x and width: x? For example, I entered height: 650, width: 800 under var chLine2 and it literally did nothing.  Any help is appreciated, especially as I'm doing my best to learn all of this.  Ideally, it would look like this: https://www.codeply.com/go/3l6UhaQEhq/bootstrap-4-chartjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col">
                <h4>Bootstrap 4 Chart.js</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row my-2">
            <div class="col-md-6 py-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chLine"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 py-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chBar"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row py-2">
            <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chDonut1"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chDonut2"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 py-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <canvas id="chDonut3"></canvas>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.js"></script>

<script>
/* chart.js chart examples */

// chart colors
var colors = ['#007bff','#28a745','#333333','#c3e6cb','#dc3545','#6c757d'];

/* large line chart */
var chLine = document.getElementById("chLine");
var chartData = {
  labels: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [589, 445, 483, 503, 689, 692, 634],
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderColor: colors[0],
    borderWidth: 4,
    pointBackgroundColor: colors[0]
  }
//   {
//     data: [639, 465, 493, 478, 589, 632, 674],
//     backgroundColor: colors[3],
//     borderColor: colors[1],
//     borderWidth: 4,
//     pointBackgroundColor: colors[1]
//   }
  ]
};
if (chLine) {
  new Chart(chLine, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    responsive: true
  }
  });
}

/* large pie/donut chart */
var chPie = document.getElementById("chPie");
if (chPie) {
  new Chart(chPie, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: ['Desktop', 'Phone', 'Tablet', 'Unknown'],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: [colors[1],colors[0],colors[2],colors[5]],
          borderWidth: 0,
          data: [50, 40, 15, 5]
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [{
      beforeDraw: function(chart) {
        var width = chart.chart.width,
            height = chart.chart.height,
            ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.restore();
        var fontSize = (height / 70).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        var text = chart.config.data.datasets[0].data[0] + "%",
            textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
            textY = height / 2;
        ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();
      }
    }],
    options: {layout:{padding:0}, legend:{display:false}, cutoutPercentage: 80}
  });
}

/* bar chart */
var chBar = document.getElementById("chBar");
if (chBar) {
  new Chart(chBar, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [589, 445, 483, 503, 689, 692, 634],
      backgroundColor: colors[0]
    },
    {
      data: [639, 465, 493, 478, 589, 632, 674],
      backgroundColor: colors[1]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        barPercentage: 0.4,
        categoryPercentage: 0.5
      }]
    }
  }
  });
}

/* 3 donut charts */
var donutOptions = {
  cutoutPercentage: 85,
  legend: {position:'bottom', padding:5, labels: {pointStyle:'circle', usePointStyle:true}}
};

// donut 1
var chDonutData1 = {
    labels: ['Bootstrap', 'Popper', 'Other'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [74, 11, 40]
      }
    ]
};

var chDonut1 = document.getElementById("chDonut1");
if (chDonut1) {
  new Chart(chDonut1, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: chDonutData1,
      options: donutOptions
  });
}

// donut 2
var chDonutData2 = {
    labels: ['Wips', 'Pops', 'Dags'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [40, 45, 30]
      }
    ]
};
var chDonut2 = document.getElementById("chDonut2");
if (chDonut2) {
  new Chart(chDonut2, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: chDonutData2,
      options: donutOptions
  });
}

// donut 3
var chDonutData3 = {
    labels: ['Angular', 'React', 'Other'],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: colors.slice(0,3),
        borderWidth: 0,
        data: [21, 45, 55, 33]
      }
    ]
};
var chDonut3 = document.getElementById("chDonut3");
if (chDonut3) {
  new Chart(chDonut3, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: chDonutData3,
      options: donutOptions
  });
}

/* 3 line charts */
var lineOptions = {
    legend:{display:false},
    tooltips:{interest:false,bodyFontSize:11,titleFontSize:11},
    scales:{
        xAxes:[
            {
                ticks:{
                    display:false
                },
                gridLines: {
                    display:false,
                    drawBorder:false
                }
            }
        ],
        yAxes:[{display:false}]
    },
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 6,
            right: 6,
            top: 4,
            bottom: 6
        }
    }
};

var chLine1 = document.getElementById("chLine1");
if (chLine1) {
  new Chart(chLine1, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
              borderColor:'#ffffff',
              data: [10, 11, 4, 11, 4],
              fill: false
            }
          ]
      },
      options: lineOptions
  });
}
var chLine2 = document.getElementById("chLine2");
if (chLine2) {
  new Chart(chLine2, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['A','B','C','D','E'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
              borderColor:'#ffffff',
              data: [4, 5, 7, 13, 12],
              fill: false
            }
          ]
      },
      options: lineOptions
  });
}

var chLine3 = document.getElementById("chLine3");
if (chLine3) {
  new Chart(chLine3, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
          labels: ['Pos','Neg','Nue','Other','Unknown'],
          datasets: [
            {
              backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
              borderColor:'#ffffff',
              data: [13, 15, 10, 9, 14],
              fill: false
            }
          ]
      },
      options: lineOptions
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is Bootstrap working? You should be able to use bootstrap - [CDN](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) -  to achieve the desired output (in fact, you provided us with a working example.) You can learn more about how "cards" function in bootstrap here: [Bootstrap Cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/)

Comment: Thank you.  This helped me resize the graphs as I needed.  I'm about 80% there though because they are all stacked in one column.  I was hoping to have it display like the Codeply example with the line and bar graph in one row and the 3 donut charts in the second row.  I struggled to find guidance for there and when I did, it didn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you use the layout that's provided in the codepen and just swap in your graphs? Also, providing a working example, such as a codepen or fiddle, would make solving whatever issue you have trivial